# How to use Sharedpreference to store an int?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I tried to use sharedpreference to store an int, that int changes it's id according to what the user choose, I don't know how to store the one that the user choose and how to read it, my main concern now is how to store I will figure how to read it later but please could someone tell me how to fix this problem.

here is my MainActivity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

static int tophone;
ImageView display;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tophone = R.drawable.iv1;
    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv4);
    Button setWp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setWp);

    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    setWp.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.iv1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv1);
        tophone = R.drawable.iv1;
        break;
    case R.id.iv2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv2);
        tophone = R.drawable.iv2;
        break;
    case R.id.iv3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv3);
        tophone = R.drawable.iv3;
        break;
    case R.id.iv4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv4);
        tophone = R.drawable.iv4;
        break;
    case R.id.setWp:
        Toast WpSet = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), tophone);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
          wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
          } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WpSet.show();
        break;
```

as you can see I want to store the id of the image which is "tophone".
I want to store the id so I could refer to it in a broadcastreciever.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code that you are using to try and store it in SharedPrefs?

Comment: the "int tophone" @codeMagic

Comment: But you say you have tried to use SharedPrefs yet you don't show any code indicating so which would allow us to tell you what you are doing wrong. If you just want an example then there are plenty on the Internet and the docs.

Comment: I suggest you apply proper indentation. It makes your code easier to read.

Comment: it's was a mess so i erased all the sharedprefs code @codeMagic

Answer (score 4):

Small example for you:

Set:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("your_int_key", yourIntValue);
editor.commit();
```

Get:

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 int myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", 0);
```

To get int value from `SharedPrefs` in `BroadReceiver`:

You can use Context from `onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1)` of `BroadReceiver`.

```
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1)
 {
     SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);                                                  
 }
```

Comment: Just name for example "amount", "size"

Comment: it says the local value of sp is not used in the broadcastreceiver

Comment: Please edit you're code and show how you try to get dat from preferences.